# How to resume/unpause a node writable stream after it's been paused?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I'm implementing a writable stream and I don't get how to **unpause** it after it's been paused.

The documentation says that to pause a writable stream one should return `false`, and to unpause it afterwards, the `drain` event should be emitted.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback

That's exactly what I think I do, but it doesn't unpause the stream, but closes the pipe instead while there is new data on the input.

Specifically:

1. I call: `this.emit('drain');`
2. `_write()` is never called again, and pipe just exists.

Here is an example:
https://replit.com/@OnkelTem/ExtrovertedSlushyOutcomes#index.js

(To run it, please switch to the "Shell" tab and issue: `node index.js`)

As you see, it stops after emitting 'drain'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without any code it will be difficult to help.

Comment: It's on its way :) About to update the question...
UPDATE. https://replit.com/@OnkelTem/ExtrovertedSlushyOutcomes#index.js

Comment: The code should be in the question, though :)